# Instead of insert trigger VS For insert Triggers in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Edited: My question is since there is an insert statement in the instead off insert trigger, then it should call insert trigger from inside the instead off insert trigger and which should avoid inserting row in the testtable. What my observation is that for insert trigger is firing but after instead off trigger which already has inserted the new row in the testable. For insert trigger is raising error but instead off trigger has already inserted a row in testtable. Why for insert trigger is not called from inside the instead off insert trigger?

I have two triggers on the table called TestTable. One is Instead of insert trigger and second is After insert trigger. First instead of insert trigger will fire and then for insert trigger.What it does that it inserts new row in TestTable and CopyTable, but not in AuditTable.

My question is why insert trigger is not fired from instead of trigger? It should because it is also using insert query in it. Why TestTable get the new inserted row?

My table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Age] [int] NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

My SQL Query:

```
Insert into dbo.TestTable values ('Waleed',24,'10-2-2015','Lahore');
```

My instead of insert trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[utInsteadoff]
   ON  [dbo].[TestTable] 
   Instead of Insert
AS 
    Declare @Name as nvarchar(50)
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Insert into dbo.TestTable (Name,Age,DOB,Address) Select Name,Age,DOB,Address From inserted; 
    Insert into dbo.CopyTable (Id,Name,Age,DOB,Address) Select Id,Name,Age,DOB,Address From inserted;  

END
```

After insert Trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[insertTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[TestTable] 
   AFTER Insert
AS 
 Declare @Name as nvarchar(50)
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     Set @Name = (Select Name from inserted)


 If (@Name = 'Waleed')
    Raiserror('You Cannot Enter Waleed Name',10,1)
  Else
 Begin 

    Insert into dbo.AuditTable (ID,Name,Age,DOB,Location)
    Select ID,Name,Age,DOB,Address from inserted
    -- Insert statements for trigger here
end
END
```

Comment: Also your after trigger seems to naively assume that all inserts will always be single row. Your logic may fail if you have an insert of two or more rows and all but one have the name waleed.

Comment: Yes @AaronBertrand I agree. Mine after trigger logic will fail if there are more than one rows. But my question still remain there. Why instead off insert trigger not firing after insert trigger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is why insert trigger is not fired from instead of trigger? It should because it is also using insert query in it. Why TestTable get the new inserted row?

The `INSTEAD OF` trigger replaces the original insert. So the code:

```
Insert into dbo.TestTable (Name,Age,DOB,Address) 
Select Name,Age,DOB,Address From inserted;
```

...is executed **instead of** the original insert:

```
Insert into dbo.TestTable values ('Waleed',24,'10-2-2015','Lahore');
```

The actions in the *instead of* trigger are completed before constraints are checked, and before any `AFTER` triggers fire.

When the *instead of* trigger completes, a row has been added to the *TestTable* and *CopyTable* tables. Note though that the transaction is still active at this point, so the changes are not yet permanent.

Next, the *after trigger* fires. It sees the name 'Waleed' in the *inserted* table, prints a message, but does not rollback the changes made so far in the transaction (including the rows added by the *instead of* trigger). No row is added to the *AuditTable*.

If the condition that checked for the name 'Waleed' also performed a rollback, everything would be rolled back, and no rows would be added to any table.